# Jacoco maven plugin with maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, integration-testing, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate coverage reports for my integration tests using Maven Surefire Plugin and Maven Jacoco Plugin. According to the documentation, `<forkCount>` cannot be set to zero. However, I'm encountering failures in my tests if I don't set it to zero. I've been struggling with this issue for quite some time now, and unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights on how to address this situation while maintaining compliance with quality standards. Thank you for your help.

Comment: How should we know what your code is doing? What the failure message (log output) contains etc. ? Which Maven, Surefire/Failsafe PLugin, JaCoCo Version and JDK version you are using? What kind of failures ?

Comment: My tests just return various errors, i think this is related to deadlock. Im using jacoco maven plugin 0.8.8, surefire 3.1.2 and JDK 17. @khmarbaise

Comment: Various errors? Which? jacoco use a more recent version 0.8.11 also use more recent version of surefire 3.2.5 and a full pom, error log etc. and code would be helpful as mentioned earlier... otherwise it's hard to even guess...